# Ruby: How to download a gem source code if it's not published on github?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I downloaded a gem `gem unpack font-awesome-rails`, but there is no `.gemspec` file. In this specific case the author published a cource code on github, but what if there won't be one. How to get a full source code of a gem?

Answer (score 2):

Ask the author for the source code. If they don't want to give you the source code, then there is no way.